# How do I ask an if statement in python (selenium webdriver) for a class value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to check if the class value is 'pointer gray gray', I'm not sure how to do it and i've looked at several posts and youtube videos and I still cannot find it. Here are the first few parts of the html source I'm looking at.

```
<span _ngcontent-c40="" apppriceratiocolor="" class="pointer gray gray" tabindex="0">1.09x</span?
<span _ngcontent-c40="" apppriceratiocolor="" class="pointer blue blue" tabindex="0">1.76x</span>
<span _ngcontent-c40="" apppriceratiocolor="" class="pointer blue blue" tabindex="0">2.16x</span>
```

entire project (it's very small and I'm working on the very bottom part with the if statement) - https://pastebin.com/we6GyvBf

I haven't tried anything because I have absoloutely no idea how to write this part of the program. I am aiming for something something like this -

```
while True:

    try:
    firstRecentCrash = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='pointer gray gray'])[1]"))
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='pointer gray gray'])[2]"))
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='pointer gray gray'])[3]"))
    )
    finally:
        enterBetAmount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(betAmount)
        enterBetMultiplierAmount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='number']").send_keys(betMultiplier)
        clickPlaceBet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bet-button']").click()
```

Comment: I don't really have any, but this is the entire project, it's not very big, I'll put it in the main post

Comment: But Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service - can you show us what you have tried so far, and what's stopping you from continuing?

Comment: The only thing that stopped me is that I don't know how to make an if statement, all I have so far is a small if statement that finds the xpath indexes of the 3 spans i posted, and I want to know how to make an if statement on how I could see if the class is 'pointer gray gray' so I can run a script on the page

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking. You "ask" an if statement by writing an if statement. What exactly is the problem with this that you are asking about?

Comment: Are you familiar with [``if`` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) at all? The code shown seems to be bash or similar, not Python.

Comment: I don't know the line of code required to see if the class name is 'pointer gray gray'.

Comment: Yes I know, i'm not done with the if statement,

Comment: I've added a try statement with a finally at the end, do you think this might work?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: if you have to use pastebin then you could set `highlight: python` and it could use colors to make code more readable.

Comment: your code with `@class='pointer gray gray'` seems OK - so maybe your problem is totally different. If you would create minimal working code with real URL to page which makes problem then we could simply copy it and test it.

Comment: if you want to get class in some element then `element = find_element(...)` and later `element.get_attribute("class")`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class of an element with

```
element.get_attribute("class")
```

so you can check with

```
myclass = "pointer grey grey" 
if (myclass == span1.get_attribute("class") and
    myclass == span2.get_attribute("class") and
    myclass == span3.get_attribute("class") ):
```

Comment: Ok thank you, i will try this and update you on how it goes

Comment: what is element.get_attribute("class")

do i have to rename something in there be cause i am getting an error

"NameError: name 'element' is not defined"

Comment: I wrote 'element' as a standin for your actual element that you want to check. You have to save your element in a variable, like `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your x path")'.

Comment: Those span1, span2, span3 I wrote are your span tags from your question.

Comment: do you think this may work? https://pastebin.com/H3PUFvxn -> the 22, 23, and 24 are for the specific 3 elements i want to get, as there are multiple spans with classes in them, and those three numbers are the ones in the list that I want.

Comment: I think it should. Just try it and see if it works.

Comment: @stinkiepinkie did it solve your problem?